# Open CV remove 2 colors with black

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, colors, mask

I have this PNG image

[image]

I want to replace baground (green color and gray color) with black color. And text with pure white color (currently if you zoom you will see that around the digits there are some blur)

I tried

```
image = cv2.imread("image1.png")
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
h,s,v = cv2.split(hsv)

mask = cv2.inRange(image, (0,0,0), (37, 160, 180))
newimage= cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask)
```

the color is changed but not black

Comment: All you should have to do on this image is convert to grayscale and threshold.

Comment: if you felt like it, you could stick to inRange, but select the white text instead. that's equivalent to a threshold for this data. -- your selected HSV range has no relation at all to this picture. green has a hue angle of around 120 degrees, so that's about 60 in OpenCV's uint8 mapping of hues (0 .. 180).